# Cannot create owncloud admin

Tags: owncloud

I have configured owncloud many times before but this time something funny is happening: I cannot create the administrator account. I choose a username and a password, click 'Finished' and then the same page is reloaded.

Cookies are available on my browser. This happens regardless of whether I use sqlite or mysql for the database.

Does anyone have any idea about what could be the cause of this?

Comment: Have you checked error logs? It would help if you could pastebin include any specific information.

Comment: I found the apache error that might be related to this (everything else looks normal): `script '/var/www/remote.php' not found or unable to stat`

Comment: Do you have any authentication requirements defined in your server configuration? That was what caused the same behavior for me once